# Very slow SQL join

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have 2 huge mysql tables:

- table **userdetails**:id, name, address, country
- table **userdata**: id, productname, producturl, price

I want to create an excel sheet from userdata where the id is the id of a user in userdetails where country is spain, so that we have:

```
id, name, address, country, productname, producturl....
```

will a simple join help? I tried but hangs my system as i have 5million records in userdata and 20,000 records in userdetails.

can I do this in phpMyadmin? or with php be better? what is the best optimised script to use?

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table_name1
INNER JOIN table_name2
ON table_name1.column_name=table_name2.column_name
```

Comment: so your join query is taking long to finished? Do you have indexes on tables? what is the result of explain command?

Comment: yes you can do this in phpmyadmin.

Comment: SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table_name1
INNER JOIN table_name2
ON table_name1.column_name=table_name2.column_name

Comment: @karto, he said he tried join but it is taking too long. So he probably doesnt have indexes.

Comment: You should consider using indexes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> will a simple join help?

Yes.

> I tried but hangs my system as i have 5million records in userdata and 20,000 records in userdetails.

5M records isn't that much. If you joined the tables properly, and have the right indices in place, this query should be executed in very little time.

> can I do this in phpMyadmin?

You can definitely execute the query there. According to [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15066874/very-slow-sql-join/15066966#comment21186531_15066966) by [Bojan Kovacevic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1841920/bojan-kovacevic), you can even save the result as CSV so that you can open it in Excel later on, at least in recent versions.

> or with php be better?

Only if you require the result to be returned via HTTP.

> what is the best optimised script to use?

You can use the command line `mysql` client and the [`SELECT … INTO OUTFILE …` MySQL command](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select-into.html) to save the result as a CSV file you can then open in Excel.

Comment: can I do this in phpMyadmin? > yes, at least in 3.5.1. after query is executed you have export->csv for excel